# solr build does not start the solr server and throwing errors

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I build [lucene-solr source code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr) in my eclipse IDE. But when I tried to start the service in the command line using

```
${user.home}\git\lucene-solr\solr\bin>solr start
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
"Failed removing old solr logs"
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
"Failed archiving old GC logs"
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
"Failed archiving old console logs"
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
"Failed rotating old solr logs"
Error: Unable to access jarfile start.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI
```

How can I resolve this?
When I was trying to compile solr, I am getting the following error

```
Buildfile: ${user.home}\git\lucene-solr\build.xml

compile:

-check-git-state:

-git-cleanroot:

-copy-git-state:

git-autoclean:

resolve:

ivy-availability-check:

BUILD FAILED
${user.home}\git\lucene-solr\build.xml:309: The following error occurred while executing this line:
${user.home}\git\lucene-solr\lucene\build.xml:124: The following error occurred while executing this line:
${user.home}\git\lucene-solr\lucene\common-build.xml:424: ${user.home}\.ant\lib does not exist.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I have installed ant and Ivy. But there is no ${user.home}.ant\lib folder. And also how can I run solr service in debug mode

Comment: Sounds like a broken classpath or missing libraries? Have you checked if the SolrCLI class has been included anywhere? It also can't find the start.jar file, which it needs o be able to start Solr.

Comment: @MatsLindh, I am getting the following error while compiling
Buildfile: ${user.home}\git\lucene-solr\build.xml

compile:

-check-git-state:

-git-cleanroot:

-copy-git-state:

git-autoclean:

resolve:

ivy-availability-check:

BUILD FAILED
${user.home}\git\lucene-solr\build.xml:309: The following error occurred while executing this line:
${user.home}\git\lucene-solr\lucene\build.xml:124: The following error occurred while executing this line:
${user.home}\git\lucene-solr\lucene\common-build.xml:424: ${user.home}\.ant\lib does not exist.
Installed Ant and Ivy.
Any Idea?

Comment: do you really need a compiled solr? you could use binary artifact, you know that?

Comment: @Mysterion, I need to do some development. So I need to know how I can build and run. So that I can debug and test my functionality

Comment: you want to create customized version of Solr? if you need to write just some custom components - you still do not need to compile it, you could use jar dependencies

Comment: I have to make some changes in the solr code. To make one of my functionality work. So I need to compile and able to put breakpoints and check right?.  What do you mean by a custom component?

Comment: i mean, could you name the Solr class you want to change, so i could say if it's possible to do without recompiling, but rather extending the code